# Showing that two quotient spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Let $M\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$

I would like to show that $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n \times [0,1]/\sim,$ quotiented by the equivalence relation $(x,0) \sim (Mx,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n \times \mathbb{R}}/\sim'$ quotiented by the equivalence relation $(x,y) \sim'(k+M^qx,y+q)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I have a difficult time finding homeomorphism for quotient spaces and I don't know if there are any general tricks that help. So what I tried is the most naive way : *guessing*.

I did it by trial and error, the first thing to test out would be the obvious:

Let $$\varphi: (\mathbb{R^n \times \mathbb{R}}/\sim') \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n \times [0,1]/\sim)$$ $$(x,y)\rightarrow(\bar{x},\dot{y})$$
where the bar denotes reduction$\pmod {\mathbb{Z}^n}$ and the dot reduction$\pmod 1$, i.e. identifying a real with its fractional part.

But then a problem arises: I want $\varphi((x,y))=\varphi((k+M^qx,y+q))$, but instead I get $$(\bar{x},\dot{y})=(\overline{M^qx},\dot{y})$$

This is almost what I'm looking for, except for this $M^q$ which I would like to do away with. In other words, I would like to add to the "bar" modulo relation the additional identification: $M \equiv Id$.

But I don't know how to proceed from there. Should I just "do it", i.e. pretend that it is possible to define the "bar" reduction as a reduction $\pmod {\mathbb{Z}^n}$ *and* at the same time be such that $\overline{M^qx}=\bar{x}$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$? I want to make sure that it makes sense to do that because it doesn't seem as natural as "casting out" $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which can be interpreted naturally as identifying vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the vector formed by their fractional parts. Here, it would be casting out all vectors of the form $(M^q-Id)x$, but then this depends on $x$. Am I on the right track or is it completely illicit?

Comment: I didn't read all you wrote, but here's a thought : the formula for $\sim'$ looks a lot like identification of different points under a group action, where the group is $\mathbb{Z}^n\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ with structure morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ given by $q\mapsto M^q$. On the other hand, if you see $[0,1]$ as almost $\mathbb{R/Z}$ the first one looks like the action of $M$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}$, which should be about the same (and the twist of the $\rtimes$ comes from the fact that when $M$ acts, it also translates a bit of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Max Yes, this is true. Does the algebra help when it comes to finding a homeomorphism though?

Comment: It can, by showing that they are both quotients of the same space by the same action

Comment: @Max but I can't see how showing this doesn't involve finding a homeomorphism. The only thing that's intuitive there is that the modding out of $k$ is replacing $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$. Once I mod out $\mathbb{Z}^n, $I can't find a proper way to reconcile the $(x,y) \equiv (M^qx,y+q)$ with $(x,0) \equiv (Mx, 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first space is clearly $X=\mathbb{R^n\times R / Z^n\rtimes Z}$; the action being given by $(v,q)\cdot (x,y) = (v+M^qx, y+q)$. This is indeed an action : clearly $(0,0)$ acts trivially, and 
$$(v,q)(v',q')(x,y) = (v,q)(v'+M^{q'}x,y+q') = (v+M^q(v'+M^{q'}x), y+q'+q) = (v+M^qv' + M^{q+q'}x, y+q+q')=(v+M^qv', q+q')\cdot (x,y)$$, and this is the mutliplication in the semi-direct product.

How about the first one ? Well let's take a map $f:(\mathbb{R/Z})^n\times [0,1]\to X$ defined by $f(x,t) = [(x,t)]$ where $[]$ denotes the class modulo the action. Note that it is well-defined because if $x=y\mod \mathbb{Z}^n$, then $(x,s) = (y,s) \mod \mathbb{Z}^n\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$

Now $f(x,0) = [(x,0)]$ and $f(Mx,1) = [(Mx,1)]$ but $(Mx,1) = (0,1)\cdot (x,0)$ so $f(x,0) =f(Mx,1)$, so $f$ factors through $\overline{f}: (\mathbb{R/Z})^n\times [0,1]/\sim\to X$.

Moreover, $f(x,t) = f(y,s)\implies \exists v,q \mid (v,q)\cdot (x,t) = (y,s)$. But this implues $q=0$ or $1$ (have a look at the second coordinate). If $q=0$, then this implies $x=y \mod \mathbb{Z}^n$, but we started from $x,y\in (\mathbb{R/Z})^n$, so this implies $x=y$. Otherwise, $q=1$ so it implies $(x,t) = (x,0)$ and $(y,s) = (y,1)$. And now the same argument shows that $y=Mx$, so that actually our above factorization was just right :  $\overline{f}$ is injective.

Moreover, it's quite clear that $\overline{f}$ is surjective (if you have $[(x,y)]$, then $y=s \mod\mathbb{Z}$ for some $s\in [0,1]$ (maybe two if $y$ is an integer), so $[(x,y)]=[(M^{-q}x,s)]$ for some $q$)

So $\overline{f}$ is a continuous bijection. But wait, $\mathbb{R/Z}^n$ and $[0,1]$ are compact, therefore so is there product, and so is any of its quotient. Moreover, $X$ is $T_2$ as the action is properly discontinuous (or you could prove it by hand, it's not that hard) : you have a continuous bijection from a compact space to a $T_2$ space: it must be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! I wish I were blessed with your mathematical fluency. I am assuming a $T_2$ space is just a separated space (never came across this term before). I have indeed shown that the action is properly discontinuous, but I don't remember the fact that this implies the separation of the quotient space, though I do know that a continuous bijection between a compact space and a separated space is a homeomorphism. Either way this is good to know so thanks again. I don't think I could have pulled that off on my own...

Comment: Yes, $T_2$,Hausdorff, separated are all the same thing. Actually, I'm using proper discontinuity of the action *and* Hausdorffness and local compactness of $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}$. See these notes for instance for a proof : https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/M141/hausdorff.pdf (they're "loquacious" as the author states at the beginning, you can probably write less than is written there)

Comment: Really like your clear and detailed solution, my classmate and I are having trouble with a similar qns https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124645/show-two-topological-spaces-are-homeomorphic , appreciate it a lot if you could help :)